# Error implementing a rViz screen within a Qt widget for the rviz/Orbit class

Tags: c++, qt5, ros, rviz

Trying to implementing a Qt Widget with inside an rViz screen. Executing the code in Qt5 it run without problem but rViz generate the error:

> The class required for this view controller, 'rviz/Orbit', could not be loaded.
> Error:
> Could not find library corresponding to plugin rviz/Orbit. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.

more specifically the error message is as follows:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9vSQ.png)

I post below the .pro file project hoping that someone can help me...

```
QT       += core gui network printsupport multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = tifgui
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++17

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/include

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/OGRE

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0

INCLUDEPATH += $(HOME)/catkin_ws/devel/include

INCLUDEPATH += $(HOME)/catkin_ws/src/marta/marta_libraries/include

INCLUDEPATH+=$$absolute_path($$system(ls /opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/include | grep opencv),/opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/include/)

LIBS += -L/opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/lib/ -lroscpp -lroslib -lrostime -lrosconsole -lrospack -lxmlrpcpp -lroscpp_serialization -lrosconsole_log4cxx -lrosconsole_backend_interface -lcpp_common -lconsole_bridge -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lyaml-cpp -lmarblewidget-qt5 -lastro

LIBS += -L/opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lcv_bridge -lboost_filesystem -limage_transport -lcompressed_depth_image_transport -lcompressed_image_transport -limage_transport_plugins -ltheora_image_transport -limage_transport_plugins -lmessage_filters -lclass_loader -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc

LIBS += -L/opt/ros/$$(ROS_DISTRO)/lib -lrviz -lresource_retriever -ltf -ltf2 -ltf2_ros -lactionlib
```

In particular in the .cpp file i use the class rviz::VisualizationFrame:

```
rviz::VisualizationFrame *rviz_frame_;
rviz_frame_ = new rviz::VisualizationFrame();
rviz_frame_->initialize("opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/default.rviz");
ui->rviz_layout->addWidget(rviz_frame_, 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

Running rviz from the terminal

> rosrun rviz rviz

Does not present any error. I think therefore that the problem is on the linking of libraries.